# Display breakdown of CPU usage by function for unit test run

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, xunit

I have a [set of xUnit tests](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString/tree/master/Tests), which I run using Test Explorer in Visual Studio.

How can I show the CPU usage information usually available from the Visual Studio built-in diagnostic tools -- specifically, the breakdown by function -- while running a unit test set?